# How to reference a class in a folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a beginners question regarding refactoring of code. Basically I want to move some classes around and put them in folders in the projects. Here I have made a folder called MessageTypes and a new class APERAK inside it. But how do I reference it from the main form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always reference classes by their names and namespaces, it doesn't matter where the source file is located.
Howewer, usually VS puts a newly created class in a namespace that contain the folder name.
In your case, the class name including namespace will be MessageTypes.APERAK, you can use it in your main form code.
Alternatively, you can add a 'using' directive and then reference the class by name only.

```
using MessageTypes;
...
APERAK obj = new APERAK();
```